# Python Beginner's Loop (Finding Primes)

Tags: python, primes

I'm truly a beginner at python so I apologise for the lack of knowledge, but the reason I'm asking is that reading the Python manual and tutorial (http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial) I'm not unable to totally grasp how loops work. I've written some simple programs so I think I get the basics but for whatever reason this program that is meant to list all primes less than or equal to n is not working:

```
n = int(raw_input("What number should I go up to? "))
p = 2
while p <= n:
        for i in range(2, p):
                if p%i == 0:
                        p=p+1 
        print "%s" % p,
        p=p+1
print "Done"
```

The output when I enter 100 for example is:

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 27 29 31 35 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 87 89 95 97 101 Done
```

Which looks almost right but for some reason contains 27, 35, 95, which are composite of course. I've been trying to pick apart the way my loop works but I just don't see where it skips checking for divisibility suddenly. I figured that if someone had a look they could explain to me what about the syntax is causing this. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: P.S. I've already managed to write a program which does the same thing using a for loop at the top instead of a while loop. I was just trying to get a deep understanding of how this works; so I'm not really looking for suggestions about different ways to do this (though if you have some nice insights I'd love that too!)

Comment: It's not that the for loop is wrong - the algorithm is. Have you actually tried executing this on paper? If it gives you the same (wrong) result, you're understanding the loop correctly, but the algorithm is wrong

Comment: @goncalopp Well I think the algorithm works on paper: at least if what I'm executing on paper is what I wrote in python. When p gets advanced to 27 for example, the i loop should find that p is divisible by 3 when the i loop reaches 3, and then p should be cycled forward to 28. Could you help me understand where the discrepancy between my understanding and what I've written is?

Comment: @LevLivnev, and then you start checking if 28 is divisible by 4, so `i` goes to 5, and you check if 29 is divisible by 5, but you never check number less than 5.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would actually restructure the program to look like this:

```
for p in range(2, n+1):
    for i in range(2, p):
        if p % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        print p,
print 'Done'
```

This is perhaps a more idiomatic solution (using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop), and works perfectly.

The outer `for` loop iterates through all the numbers from 2 to `n`.

The inner one iterates to all numbers from 2 to `p`. If it reaches a number that divides evenly into `p`, then it breaks out of the inner loop.

The `else` block executes every time the for loop isn't broken out of (printing the prime numbers).

Then the program prints `'Done'` after it finishes.

As a side note, you only need to iterate through 2 to the square root of `p`, since each factor has a pair. If you don't get a match there won't be any other factors after the square root, and the number will be prime.

Comment: Thanks, this is really straightforward. I tried using a for loop at first but I didn't know about this alternate usage for else for a loop (execute after exhaustion), which is what was necessary here.

Answer (score 6):

Your code has two loops, one inside another.  It should help you figure out the code if you replace the inner loop with a function.  Then make sure the function is correct and can stand on its own (separate from the outer loop).

Here is my rewrite of your original code.  This rewrite works perfectly.

```
def is_prime(n):
    i = 2
    while i < n:
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True


n = int(raw_input("What number should I go up to? "))

p = 2
while p <= n:
    if is_prime(p):
        print p,
    p=p+1

print "Done"
```

Note that `is_prime()` doesn't touch the loop index of the outer loop.  It is a stand-alone pure function.  Incrementing `p` inside the inner loop was the problem, and this decomposed version doesn't have the problem.

Now we can easily rewrite using `for` loops and I think the code gets improved:

```
def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
    return True


n = int(raw_input("What number should I go up to? "))

for p in range(2, n+1):
    if is_prime(p):
        print p,

print "Done"
```

Note that in Python, `range()` never includes the upper bound that you pass in.  So the inner loop, which checks for `< n`, we can simply call `range(2, n)` but for the outer loop, where we want `<= n`, we need to add one to `n` so that `n` will be included: `range(2, n+1)`

Python has some built-in stuff that is fun.  You don't need to learn all these tricks right away, but here is another way you can write `is_prime()`:

```
def is_prime(n):
    return not any(n%i == 0 for i in range(2, n))
```

This works just like the `for` loop version of `is_prime()`.  It sets `i` to values from `range(2, n)` and checks each one, and if a test ever fails it stops checking and returns.  If it checks `n` against every number in the range and *not any* of them divide `n` evenly, then the number is prime.

Again, you don't need to learn all these tricks right away, but I think they are kind of fun when you do learn them.

Comment: It's kind of a general rule of thumb: decompose your code into useful functions, debug the functions, and then you can rely on the functions.  The best functions do one task, and are simple enough you understand clearly what they do, how they do it, and that they do it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This should work and is bit more optimized

```
import math
for i in range(2, 99):
  is_prime = True
  for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(i)+1)):
    if i % j == 0:
      is_prime = False
  if is_prime:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not re-start the `i` loop after you find a non-prime

```
p = i = 2
while p <= n:
    i = 2
    while i < p:
        if p%i == 0:
            p += 1 
            i = 1
        i += 1

    print p,
    p += 1

print "Done"
```

A `while` loop executes the body, and then checks if the condition at the top is `True`, if it is true, it does the body again.  A `for` loop executes the body once for each item in the iterator.

Comment: Are you saying that after finding a non-prime and setting p=p+1, I need to do something like continue? I tried putting continue after and it changed nothing. Could you please explain in a little more detail why the i loop does not get restarted?

Comment: @LevLivnev: Step through it in your head. Imagine that you start with `p=25`. So, you do `for i in range(2, p)`. When `i` reaches 5, that divides `25`, so you do a `p = p + 1`. So now `p=26`… and you continue on with `i=6`. That doesn't divide 26, so you go to 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13. That divides 26, so `p = p + 1`, and now `p=27`, and it tries 14 through 26, none of which divide 27, therefore 27 is prime.

Comment: @tcaswell: +1. But it might be a smaller change, and definitely would be more readable, to just break out of the `for` loop once you find that `p` isn't prime, instead of trying to increment `p` and `i` in two different places each. (The downside is that the obvious pythonic way to do that would be a `for:`/`else:`, which tends to confuse newcomers to the language…)

Comment: @abarnert Breaking out of the for loop after discovering a non-prime and advancing to p+1 is exactly what I was hoping to do, but placing a break is not doing what I hope it would. I understand what the problem is now, but without restructuring the code too much, how do I reset the i loop after a non-prime is discovered?

Comment: @LevLivnev: You don't need to reset the `i` loop—just break out of it, and next time through the `while` loop, you'll get a whole new `i` loop automatically. The only question is, how can you tell whether you finished the `i` loop normally (so `p` is prime), or by `break` (so `p` is not prime)? That's exactly what `for:`/`else:` is for, as in Volatility's answer—or, if you find that confusing (a _lot_ of new Python programmers do), you can keep track of it explicitly, as in Guudu's answer.

Comment: @abarnert In the end I realised that what I wanted to be able to do was using else: after for:, which means execute if the for: loop was exhausted. Thanks for your help, I think I'm making some progress now.

Comment: this is a very unusual way to do this; its correctness depends on testing `while i < p:`. The usual speedup of writing `while i*i < p:` will invalidate the code. This means that it is slow -- ~n^2 order of growth instead of ~n^1.5 (in number of primes). For a 1000 primes, n^0.5 = 30x slowdown. To calc 1000 primes upto 7919 it indeed took 1.5 sec on ideone - instead of some 0.05 seconds (well, actually 0.11 secs; still, ...). :) http://ideone.com/HMsnEA http://ideone.com/BTqkbA

Answer (score 1):

Please compare your snippet with the one pasted below and you will notice where you were wrong.

```
n = int(raw_input("What number should I go up to? "))
p = 2
while p <= n:
    is_prime=True
    for i in range(2, p):
        if p%i == 0:
            is_prime=False
            break;
    if is_prime==True:
        print "%d is a Prime Number\n" % p
    p=p+1
```

Comment: Your indentation is a mess. What's supposed to be inside which statements?

Comment: Indentation went wrong copying from the editor to here....It has been corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(2, p):
    if p%i == 0:
        p=p+1 
     print "%s" % p,
     p=p+1
```

I am going to tell your error only,in line 3 you are incrimenting p but actually what you are missing is your i if your i in previous case is let say 13 then it will check your loop after 13 but it is leaving 2,3,5,7,11 so its an error .that is what happening in case of 27 your i before 27 is 13 and now it will check from 14.and I don't think u need an solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n>=2:
        for i in range(2, n):
            if n%i == 0:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

To find PRIME NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a couple more improvements.

1. You know 2 is the only even prime number, so you add 2 in your list and start from 3 incrementing your number to be checked by 2.
2. Once you are past the half-way point (see above `sqrt` and `*` examples), you don't need to test for a prime number.
3. If you use a list to keep track of the prime numbers, all you need to do is to divide by those prime numbers.

I wrote my code and each of the above items would improve my code execution time by about 500%.

```
prime_list=[2]
def is_prime(a_num):
    for i in prime_list:
        div, rem = divmod(a_num, i)
        if rem == 0:
            return False    
        elif div < i:
            break;

    prime_list.append(a_num)        
    return True
```

Comment: You are not really answering the question here, you are improving on other answers. In general, please concentrate on the specific question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This in my opinion is a more optimised way. This finds all the prime numbers up to 1,000,000 in less than 8 seconds on my setup.

It is also one of my very first attempts at python, so I stand to be corrected

```
class prime:
    def finder (self):
        import math
        n = long(raw_input("What number should I go up to? "))
        for i in range(2, n):
            is_prime = True
            if i % 2 == 0:
                is_prime = False
            for j in range(3, long(math.sqrt(i) + 1), 2):
                if i % j == 0:
                    is_prime = False
                    break
            if is_prime:
                print(i)


prime().finder()
```

Comment: The question is about how to properly structure the for-loop, not about optimisation. Some advice on your code: you shouldn't put the function in a class, it's unnecessary. Just have it on its own in the module. Also, you should put import statements at the top of the module, not inside the function. You should separate input, computation and output: first ask the user for the number, then have a function that takes a number and returns a boolean indicating whether it is prime, and finally print the result of that function.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Enter a Number: ')
number=abs(int(input()))
my_List=[0,1]
def is_prime(n):
    if n in my_List:
        return True
    elif n>=2:
        for i in range(2, n):
            if n%i == 0:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False

if is_prime(number):
    print("%d is Prime!"%number)
else:
    print(number,'is not prime')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def findprime(num):
  count = 0
  for i in range(1,num+1):
    list1 = []
    for ch in range(1,i+1):
      if i%1==0 and i%ch==0:
        list1.append(ch)
    if len(list1)==2:
      count += 1
      print(i,end=", ")
  print()
  return count  
num2 = int(input("enter a number: "))
result=findprime(num2)
print("prime numbers between 1 and",num2,"are",result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more extensive example with optimization in mind for Python 3.

```
import sys

inner_loop_iterations: int = 0

def is_prime(n):
    a: int = 2
    global inner_loop_iterations

    if n == 1:
        return("Not prime")
    elif n == 2:
        return("Prime")

    while a * a <= n + 1:
        inner_loop_iterations += 1
        # This if statement reduces the number of inner loop iterations by roughy 50%
        # just weeding out the even numbers.
        if a % 2 == 0:
            a += 1
        else:
            a += 2

        if n % 2 == 0 or n % a == 0:
            return ("Not prime")
    else:
        return ("Prime")

while True:
    sys.stdout.write("Enter number to see if it's prime ('q' to quit): ")
    n = input()
    if not n:
        continue
    if n == 'q':
        break

    try:
        n = int(n)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid number")

    if n < 1:
        print("Please enter a valid number")
        continue

    sys.stdout.write("{}\n".format(is_prime(n)))
    sys.stderr.write("Inner loops: {}\n\n".format(inner_loop_iterations))
    inner_loop_iterations=0
```

This program has two main optimizations, first it only iterates from 2 to the square root of n and it only iterates through odd numbers. Using these optimizations I was able to find out that the number 1000000007 is prime in only 15811 loop iterations.

Answer (score 0):

**My fast implementation returning the first 25 primes:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from math import sqrt

def _is_prime(_num: int = None):
    if _num < 2:
        return False
    if _num > 3 and not (_num % 2 and _num % 3):
        return False
    return not any(_num % _ == 0 for _ in range(3, int(sqrt(_num) + 1), 2))

_cnt = 0
for _ in range(1, 1000):
        if _is_prime(_):
        _cnt += 1
        print(f"Prime N°: {_:,} | Count: {_cnt:,}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Better use

```
for i in range(2, p//2 + 1):
```