# How many rows of comment-less code do I have?

Tags: python

If I have a python-file with X lines, but Y rows are only occupied by comments and Z rows are just empty space, how do I find N, N=X-Y-Z?

Here is what I have tried. This is my example-code;

```
#This is a function to find prime numbers...
#..., it's taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656473/python-beginners-loop-finding-primes

primes_in_a_list = []
for p in range(2, 100):
    for i in range(2, p):
        if p % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        primes_in_a_list.append(p)

print (primes_in_a_list)
```

In the example above there are 12 rows, I would like to run another .py-file/script that prints out 8. With the code below, I get 10 as an answer.

```
x, y, z = 0, 0, 0

with open('test.py') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = [x.strip() for x in content]
for line in content:
    theline = line[2:]
    x += 1
    if theline.startswith('#'):
        y += 1
    if not theline:
        z += 1
n = x-y-z

print (n)
```

Comment: Rather than reinvent this particular wheel yourself, might I direct you to [David Wheeler's `sloccount`](https://dwheeler.com/sloccount/)?

Comment: BTW, note that `f.readline()` returns `'\n'` on an empty line, not `''`. And I wonder if you mean to have a loop that iterates over the whole file, rather than only looking at the first line. Frankly, it probably makes sense to `strip()` each line before analysis; in addition to removing the trailing `\n`, that'll also catch indented comments.

Comment: Do you want to handle multiline comments as well?

Comment: ...the edits you've made have addressed some of your problems, but you still aren't reading past the first line, even you you rename the variable from `firstline` to `line`.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to figure out how to do it. Thanks for the tips, I updated my post but now it gives an output of 10 instead of 8. @JanChristophTerasa yeah didn't think of that but that would be great aswell

Comment: BTW, the point when an answer is added is the point when it becomes impolite to further edit your question in a way that invalidates that answer.

Comment: And see https://ideone.com/dZvWuI, giving `8` instead of `10` as output.

Comment: Yeah sorry I just noticed, that was just bad timing (we posted simultaneously), not my intention.

Comment: BTW, what's the intent of `line[2:]`? How will you recognize a comment if you're ignoring the first characters?

Comment: Oh I misunderstood.. I thought that every `line` would start with `\n`.

Comment: No, every line *ends* with `\n` (and it's one character, not two; `r'\n'` is two characters, but to write that as a non-raw string would be `'\\n'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep` and `wc` in a shell:

```
grep -vE '^[[:space:]]*#|^$' test.py | wc -l
```

This will give `8`.

- `^[[:space:]]*#` will match zero or more whitespace (`[[:space:]]`) followed by a `#` after the beginning of the line `^`.
- `^$` matches the beginning of the line `^` followed by the end of the line `$`
- `|` is an or-operator, matching if either expression is fulfilled
- The `-E` option to `grep` enables extended regexp
- The `-v` option to `grep` reverses the match, i.e. it returns the lines which did *not* match the pattern
- `wc` counts the number of newlines, words or bytes in a file or stream, the `-l` option only returns the (new)line count
- The `|` in the shell pipes the (standard) output of the left command to the (standard input of the) command on the right.

Matching multiline comments is more difficult, since you need to find the lines between two markers. It might be possible using `sed`, but I am not quite sure right now how to do it.

Comment: `\s` isn't guaranteed to work even with `grep -E` (depends on your standard C library's regex functions offering functionality that isn't in the POSIX standard); more portable to use `[[:space:]]`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I edited the answer to include it since it worked for me! @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OK, I will edit accordingly, thanks for the tip.

Comment: (Here I thought, from the Python tag, that the OP wanted a Python answer, and was doing this as a learning exercise rather than a practical matter).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The OP said "I would like to run another .py-file/**script** that prints out 8" (emphasis mine), so I thought shell/grep/wc was fine.

Answer (score 1):

`with` just opens the file; it doesn't iterate over its contents.

If you want to read past the first line, add a loop *inside*, as:

```
with open('test.py') as f:
    for line in f.readline()
        x += 1
        if line.startswith('#'):
            y += 1
        if line.startswith('\n') or line.startswith('\r\n'):
            z += 1
```